# The best way to compare strings

Tags: r

In R I have `data` like this

```
ID 
Peter
peter
peterr
john
johN
JOhn
...
```

I simply want to collect all the person, for example all that have the name like Peter should be collected, so my new data-set would be like this

```
ID
Peter, peter, peterr
john, johN, JOhn
...
```

So I want to write a code that take `peter, Peter, peterr` and collect them and I want to do it for all the names.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Comparing `Peter` against `peter` is one thing, the only issue being case, but equating `peter` and `peterr` is another altogether.  You would have to give us all the logic for name comparisons if you want a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `adist()` calculates the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between strings.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("Peter", "peter", "peterr",   "john",   "johN",   "JOhn"))
adist(df1$ID)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    2    5    5    5
[2,]    1    0    1    5    5    5
[3,]    2    1    0    6    6    6
[4,]    5    5    6    0    1    2
[5,]    5    5    6    1    0    3
[6,]    5    5    6    2    3    0
```

Smaller distance values indicate greater similarity. The index (row) number of the six words "Peter", "peter" etc. within the vector `df1$ID` corresponds to the column / row number in the matrix.

The programming task then consists in identifying the pairs which have a small distance. Here is one possibility to find pairs with minimal difference:

```
dm <- adist(df1$ID)
dm <- dm*upper.tri(dm)
which(dm == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   1   2
#[2,]   2   3
#[3,]   4   5
```

These three pairs (1,2), (2,3) and (4,5) denote the index number of the strings that can be considered to be very similar. Those are: "Peter" and "peter", "peter" and "peterr", as well as "john" and "johN".

```
data.frame(apply(which(dm == 1, arr.ind=TRUE), 2, function(x) df1$ID[x]))
#    row    col
#1 Peter  peter
#2 peter peterr
#3  john   johN
```

The similarity threshold can be lowered by using, e.g., `which(dm > 0 & dm < 3, arr.ind=TRUE)`. This results in a larger number of similar pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a matrix of string distances between each entry on that list and every other item on that list... it'll be huge. Then you simplify that list based on some level of acceptability... for example `StringDistance <2`.

I designed this script to do just that: https://github.com/mexindian/DataProcessing/blob/master/misspellingFixer.R
See if it solves your problem

Answer (score -2):

Two alternative suggestions:

`gsub()`from `stringr` package. For example if you want to equate `Peter` in your variable `ID`:

`gsub("pet", "Peter", data, ignore.case = TRUE)`

This option can be tedious if you have a number of levels to equate.

An alternative, on the basis of @Amit Kohli proposal, is another package [`fuzzyjoin`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) that might be useful for your purposes.